# Android Emulator перестал работать корректно после обновления AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Как понятно из вопроса я обновил Android Studio, и все эмуляторы перестали отправлять запросы и осуществлять вообще любую работу с интернетом, то есть браузер в эмуляторе не грузится тоже. Пытаюсь найти что то в настройках студии, пока безуспешно.

Пробовал ставить

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
```

Не помогло.

Вот что есть в лог файлах

> Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argumen

Может кто то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Интернет через Wifi? Операционная система какая?

Comment: Кабель. Винда 10